# re.search password checking error

Tags: python, regex, passwords, character

My code is functioning, but the first line of code defining what makes a strong password causes the rest of the code to return back as nothing. For example, as the first line of code is searching for a character which is a number, any of the code from there on, causes the code to not print the message though the requirements have been met. If I change it from searching for a digit to searching for a capital or lowercase character, then any coding afterwards will not function if the code requires looking for a capital or lowercase etc.

```
import re
password = str(input("Please enter the password you wish to test the strength of.\n"))
if re.search(r'[0-9]', password): 
    if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
        if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
            print("Your password strength is STRONG.")
elif re.search(r'[a-z]', password) and re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    print("Your password strength is MEDIUM.")
elif re.search(r'[0-9]', password) and re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    print("Your password strength is MEDIUM.")
elif re.search(r'[a-z]', password) and re.search(r'[0-9]', password):
    print("Your password strength is MEDIUM.")
elif re.search(r'[A-Z]', password) or re.search(r'[a-z]', password) or re.search(r'[0-9]', password):
    print("Your password strength is WEAK.")
```

Comment: Does the length of the password influence the strength rating you are giving it here?

Comment: If the password is between 6 and 12 characters then only the strength will be tested. However the length does not affect the strength, its just what characters it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could refactor it to something like this

```
import re
strength = 0
password = str(input("Please enter the password you wish to test the strength of.\n"))
if re.search(r'[0-9]', password):
    strength += 1
if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    strength += 1
if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
    strength += 1

if strength == 3
    print("Your password strength is STRONG.")

if strength == 2:
    print("Your password strength is MEDIUM.")

if strength == 1:
    print("Your password strength is WEAK.")
```

although, i am sure there are better way of doing it, try thinking out of the box :D

Comment: Would that method work if I used password.isupper or password.islower or password.isdigit as well?

Comment: most likely not, for example, "9gag" as stated by jez, would return False for all those method.  too bad there isn't a hasupper, haslower or hasdigit method

Answer (score 1):

Follow through the logic of the code yourself using the password "9gag".  There's a `[0-9]` in there but *not* an `[A-Z]`.  The interpreter enters the first `if`, and is therefore excluded from the subsequent `elif`s, but it doesn't enter the nested `if` and lands in limbo.

This approach might be easier:

```
hits = [ re.search(r'[0-9]', password) != None, re.search(r'[A-Z]', password) != None, re.search(r'[a-z]', password) != None ]
strength = sum( hits )
```

Comment: now this is what i call thinking out of the box, bool is treated as a int on python, although it might be a little complex to understand for people who is just learning.

Comment: Yes. To clarify, then: each term `re.search( pattern, passord ) != None`  yields either `True` (matched) or `False` (unmatched).  In `sum` as in many other numerical operations, a `True` is treated as a 1 and a `False` is treated as a 0, so for example `sum( [ True, True, False ] )` is 2.

Answer (score 0):

I once tried to implement a MUCH more advanced password strength algorithm (involving shannon entropy and modifications of that), but in the end I have seen that this is a hard problem and one can't really say when a password is good.

The only thing you maybe can determine easily is when a password is really bad.

So maybe just educating the users to chose passwords wisely or just creating random passwords when appropriate is the best.

Putting arbitrary rules on passwords is often rather annoying. E.g. if somebody uses a password manager to generate random passwords, they might fail your rules, but still are good passwords because they are random.